# SSMS 2018 shows splash screen then closes

Tags: sql

We installed SQL Server Management Studio 2018 (v18 GA) on a Server 2012.  The SSMS program presents the splash screen then closes immediately.  After reviewing the logs, there isn't any entry in the Event Viewer; I suspect that it's closing cleanly, but I don't know why.  I attempted to run the repair on the following packages from other research:  Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86/x64) - 14.16.27029.  I repaired both and the SSMS package using the installer, but the same issue occurs.  Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue with the same configuration...

Comment: I think we're abandoning the v18 and going to an older release for now.

Comment: SSMS 17.9 opened without issue after an uninstall of v18.  I never rebooted between uninstall/install.

Answer (score 7):

This has come up on DBA Stack Exchange which seems to solve the problem:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237086/sql-server-management-studio-18-wont-open-only-splash-screen-pops-up?

Answer (score 0):

I just overlaid the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies with the copy from ..\PrivateAssemblies\Interop and the IDE opens. (Thanks to Mitch for discovering the offending DLL name.)